# Having trouble with SQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using this query (I changed it):

```
// SQL query
$squl = "INSERT INTO 'messages' ('id','name' ,'email' ,'subject' ,'content','userid') VALUES ( null,'".$name."',  '".$mail."',  '".$subject."',  '".$content."','');"; 

// mysql query
$query = mysql_query($squl) or die("message query problem: ".  mysql_error());
```

I get this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''messages' ('id','name' ,'email' ,'subject' ,'content','userid' )VALUES ( null,'' at line 1

What is causing this?

Comment: You're trying to assign five values to six columns. It looks like you have a period instead of a comma between the last two values; could be a typo?

Comment: thanks but it doesn't work yet but thanks for spend your valuable time to find the problem :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

``` .``) ``` You used a period here instead of a comma so the function is only receiving 5 columns when it needs 6.

Update:

As the commenter below points out, you've replaced the backticks with quotation marks.

```
$squl="INSERT INTO `messages` (`id`,`name` ,`email` ,`subject` ,`content`,`userid` )VALUES ( null,'$name',  '$mail',  '$subject',  '$content','');";
```

Comment: thanks a lot and i changed it to "$squl="INSERT INTO 'messages' ('id','name' ,'email' ,'subject' ,'content','userid' )VALUES ( 'NULL','$name',  '$mail',  '$subject',  '$content','');";"  but then i got this error "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''messages' ('id','name' ,'email' ,'subject' ,'content','userid' )VALUES ( 'NULL'' at line 1"

Comment: Please update your question at the top with your code. Remember to indent it by four spaces so SO treats it as a code block. It will be difficult to troubleshoot your syntax error via comments.

Comment: @hatef:now you've replaced all the backticks with regular quotes. You cannot use quotes around fieldnames - that turns them into strings so they're not treated as fieldnames anymore.

Comment: i changed it but it doesn't work yet sorry for taking your time :(

Comment: What error message are you getting with the SQL code in my updated answer? It's valid SQL so there must be an issue with one of your PHP variables.

Comment: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''messages' ('id','name' ,'email' ,'subject' ,'content','userid' )VALUES ( null,'' at line 1" still

Comment: Are you using this?     ``$squl="INSERT INTO `messages` (`id`,`name` ,`email` ,`subject` ,`content`,`userid` )VALUES ( null,'$name',  '$mail',  '$subject',  '$content','');";`` If you copy and paste that and you still get a syntax error, then you have a problem with your PHP variables. Post the output of `echo($squl);`

Comment: with changing (`) to (') yes i do

Comment: Well don't change ` to ' then. You can't enclose column names with quotations as someone earlier told you.

Comment: it result is : INSERT INTO 'messages' ('id','name' ,'email' ,'subject' ,'content','userid' )VALUES ( null,'asdasd', 'qwetre', 'rte', 'qwe','');

Comment: Stop using single quotes in the column names. It's as simple as that.

Comment: doesn't work! thanks for your help i think maybe i should review all program again. - you and other guys helped me a lot  :) -

Answer (score 2):

```
(id,name ,email ,subject ,content,userid )

( NULL,".$name.", ".$mail.", ".$subject.", ".$content."**.**``);
```

you are using '.' instead of ,

Answer (score 1):

Well, that's about the clearest message you get from SQL. You try to insert 5 values into 6 columns.

The problem that there's no comma between the last two values. Instead there's a `.` which makes the parser think it's only one value.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to insert into 6 columns:

1. `id`
2. `name`
3. `email`
4. `subject`
5. `content`
6. `userid`

But have only specified 5 values:

1. `NULL`
2. `$name`
3. `$mail`
4. `$subject`
5. `$content`

Answer (score 0):

You've got a dot where you should have a comma:

```
".$subject."`,  `".$content."`.``);";
```

Change that last dot to a comma and you should be golden

Answer (score 0):

You've got 6 fields in your fields list, but are inserting only 5 values in your values list. Looks like you've got a `.` instead of a `,`:

```
`,  `".$subject."`,  `".$content."`.``
                                   ^--- here
```

As well, there is NO reason to use repeated string concatenation as you are. PHP can insert variables into double-quoted strings quiet easily:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO .... (...) VALUES (NULL, '$name', '$mail', '$subject', '$content', '')";
```

Note that the 'null' value is not quoted. Backticks are there to escape reserved words. If you intend to insert a real database null, then use the bare word `null`. If you want a literal string 'null' to go in, then quote it normally: `'null'`.

Comment: i found it and also changed 'null' to null thanks but it doesn't work yet!

Answer (score -1):

You have six fields listed the first set of parentheses and only five fields in VALUES. That's what column count means.